# How to fix 'NameError: name 'imgpath' is not defined' error in Python3 and tkinter to show a picture

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, pyephem

I want to show the current moon phase in tkinter for today or a specific date. When I run the code I get the Error: "NameError: name 'imgpath' is not defined". I understand that I have to press the button first. How can I set the variable "imgpath" to an global variable.

I want to change the picture when I choose another date.

```
from tkinter import *
import ephem
from datetime import date, datetime
fenster = Tk()
def button_action():
    station = ephem.Observer()
    dates = dateeingabe.get()
    if (dates == ""):
        station.date = datetime.utcnow()
    else:
        station.date = dateeingabe.get()
    #Mondphase
    Moon = ephem.Moon()
    Moon.compute(station)
    drei = round(Moon.phase, 0)
    eins = ephem.next_full_moon(station.date)
    zwei = ephem.next_new_moon (station.date)
    if drei == 0:
        phasen = int(0)
    elif drei == 100:
        phasen = int(100)
    elif (ephem.next_full_moon(station.date) > ephem.next_new_moon(station.date)):
        phasen = int(100-drei+100)
    else:
        phasen = int(drei)

    imgpath = str("/home/user/moon/"+str(phasen)+".png")

pic = PhotoImage(file=imgpath)
picz = Label(fenster, image=pic)
dateeingabe = Entry(fenster, bd=5, width=40)
start_button = Button(fenster, text="Start", command=button_action)
dateeingabe.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
start_button.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
picz.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
fenster.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program executes top to bottom, so when you try to set the path to imgpath in

```
pic = PhotoImage(file=imgpath)
```

It throws an error because imgpath is defined once you call button_action in this code, two lines below:

```
start_button = Button(fenster, text="Start", command=button_action)
```

To convert imgpath to a global variable you can declare it as so :

```
global imgpath
```

Although that will not solve your problem as you're calling the PhotoImage before you're calling button_action.

Maybe try shifting that code below the Button code?

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a another solution: When I enter a date, press the button, tkinter creates a window with the pictures.